# Email not working on laravel when using Gsuite mail

Tags: php, laravel-4, google-workspace

I recently configured My domain to Gsuite email. I using it for my laravel application.
The below error occur when using Gsuite email but it is working fine with other gmail accounts and other email servers. Please help with me to find this issue.

Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v4sm27577447pgf.20 - gsmtp "

My email Configuration

```
return array(
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => '{{Mydomain email}}', 'name' => '{{myname}}'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => '{{mydomain email}}',
'password' => '{{app password}}',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
);
```

Comment: Message seems pretty clear to me. Are you using the proper credentials? full email address as requested? (somemail@gmail.com) ? Have you tried the troubleshooting steps as descripted in the link?

Comment: go to https://myaccount.google.com/ and make sure your server is allowed to send use your account for send emails

Comment: yes i'm using proper credentials. Mail id end with our domain name ex: (sales@mydomain.uk)

Comment: Two steps authentication also configured correctly

Comment: Did you allow `Less secure apps`?

Comment: After enabled less secure apps it working fine on localhost but in live server it throws below error "stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`server1.search2reach.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.gmail.com' "

Comment: Try an application password rather than your login password

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing this problem
i used following credentials

```
'driver' => 'sendmail',
'host' => 'mail.gmail.com',
```

and it worked